# echo youtube video src in ifram with php

Tags: php, html, youtube

This is what I wanna do:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//<?php $key="youtubevideo"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This is what happens:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="560" height="315" allowfullscreen="" src="//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuRbVuQNppU">
```

How can I echo this correctly?

Thank you

Comment: <iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "youtubevideo", true); ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,
change $key="youtubevideo" ----> $key='youtubevideo'

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php $key='youtubevideo'; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```